# 1.5 ton AC on solar power through inverter

Tags: inverter, solar-energy

I am planning to design my design in such a way that I can run my 1.5 ton AC easily during daytime i.e. 9am to 5pm plus some load of around 500 watt. 
I am planning to use following:

1 - 5000va/4000W 48vdc pure sine wave inverter (power factor 0.8)

2 - solar panels 250 x 12 = 3000 Watt

3 - 4 x 12V 200ah batteries

Will this setup work? theoretically it should.

Comment: What is the electrical load of your AC?

Comment: 1.5 ton alternating current? I guess it's some sort of vehicle, but I'm not familiar with that abbreviation.

Comment: AC=Air conditioner.

Comment: It will depend on how much power you really get out of your solar cells (total watt hours suring daylight) and how much power your A/C draws for how long.  We don't know the load of your A/C, and have no way of guessing how much power you will really collect over a day.

Comment: You will no doubt have some fun trying to charge your 4 batteries in series (48V) with a solar system that puts out only 12V.

Comment: @JRE thanks for that, now I know that 1 ton is not 1000 kg (that would be a tonne) but 12000 BTU per hour (among other things it could mean). Units are really horrible.

Comment: @Arsenal: No argument about the units.  They suck.

Comment: @JRE it is 36V per panel

Comment: Still a problem.  36V is less than 48V that the inverter wants.

Comment: @JRE so u mean i should get more voltage from panels than what my battery needs?

Comment: I mean you have to have 48V to feed the inverter.  You have to get that from the batteries (4 batteries at 12V in series) and you have to be able to charge them, so you will need 48V (at least, actually more) to charge the batteries in series.

Comment: @JRE i can connect in few and few in series in order to increase voltage and current

Comment: @Arsenal,  a ton of cooling is the amount of cooling you'd get from melting a ton (910 kg) of ice. If done over 24 hours it works out at about 3.5 kW. The electrical energy required will be 3.5 kW/CoP (Coefficient of Performance).

Comment: @Transistor interesting, thanks for pointing that out. Even if it has been 4 years :-)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than use an inverter to power the air conditioner, you could take an air conditioner unit that is readily designed to run from DC voltage available from solar power systems.

Many companies are making DC powered air conditioner units, because for the manufacturer, it's a relatively small design change to the unit. Basically all AC units today are 'invergter driven' e.g. they have a frequency changer to drive the motor(s). That already runs from a DC voltage, which is taken from a rectifier stage, and just needs to be tweaked to accept DC input at a suitable voltage.

Here's one such solution from one manufacturer (GE innovations) that I found from Google:

[image: http://www.geinnovations.net/solar_air_conditioner.html]

http://www.geinnovations.net/solar_air_conditioner.html

Using a DC powered air conditioner unit eliminates redundant power conversions making it more efficient. It's also much more easier since the air conditioner unit can do decisions such as low voltage cut off much easier than a separate inverter which must work on a very large operating range.

Finally, solar power and cooling is a perfect match because you need the most cooling power exactly when the sun is shining and solar power is available! When it's cloudy and the solar cells generate less power, you also need less cooling!

Answer (score 1):

1.5 ton of cooling power is equivalent to 5.3 kW cooling.  Suppose you have a CoP of 2, then there is 2.7 kW of electrical load.  Add the 500 W of other load and you're at 3.2 kW load.  AT this load, the solar panels could not produce enough power in full sun to keep this running.  Nevermind cloudy days, inverter efficiency, etc.  Perhaps you could double the solar setup.

Now you may get a CoP better than 2 - some of the time.  It will depend on your weather conditions, etc.  If you have a meter, you might take some measurements of the input power at various outdoor air temperatures to be able to better describe the required input power.  Also, have you confirmed that 1.5 ton is adequate?  Perhaps a smaller unit could meet the cooling needs.

You might use a "automatic transfer switch" to revert to AC mains when you run out of juice.  That will make it forgiving of high cooling loads.

Comment: COP of 2 is really, really poor for modern units. Most minisplits I'm seeing in the 5kW range are around 4-4.5.

Comment: It's -20°C here.  CoP not the best atm.

Comment: I mean, your cooling COP would be really good at those temps... Reducing COP generally reduces maximum capacity, not input power. It's still going to draw ~1.5kW; it's just going to deliver ~3kW of heat, not 6kW